# Is it undefined behaviour to not call the destructor of an object?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, destructor

This may seem like an obvious question, however I haven't been able to find the answer written anywhere explicitly. Consider the following code:

```cpp
{
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(int), alignof(int)> storage;
    int& i = *new(&storage) int;
}
```

Here, I start the lifetime of an objected named `i` but this lifetime has no explicit "end" since there should be no call to `~int`.
I'm not sure if the answer to this question depends on whether or not the type is trivial, so I will provide this second example:

```cpp
class MyMem : public std::pmr::memory_resource
{
    std::size_t mem_size = 0u;
    char* mem_handle = nullptr;

    virtual void* do_allocate(std::size_t bytes, std::size_t) final
    {
        mem_size += bytes;
        mem_handle = static_cast<char*>(std::realloc(mem_handle, mem_size));
        return mem_handle + mem_size - bytes;
    }
    virtual void do_deallocate(void*, std::size_t, std::size_t) final {}
    virtual bool do_is_equal(const std::pmr::memory_resource&) const noexcept { return false; }

public:
    void* data() const noexcept { return mem_handle; }
};

//...
MyMem mbr;
{
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(std::pmr::vector<int>), alignof(std::pmr::vector<int>)> vec_storage;
    auto& vec = *new(&vec_storage) std::pmr::vector<int>(&mbr);
    vec.resize(N);
}
// Free the data here
std::free(mbr.data());
```

Using a custom memory resource I can get a handle to the data allocated by the call to `vector::resize` and ensure we don't leak memory. However the actual destructor call for the `vector` is missing, and so is the destructor call for each `int` object allocated in that memory.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#5

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Thanks for the link, very interesting. I read this as, *no* there is no undefined behaviour since I don't "rely on the side effects produced by the destructor"?

Comment: The vector dtor may have side effects due to deallocations. I don't know pmr though. It basically means you're safe as long as the dtor is trivial. The wording is horribly wooly however and I try to avoid second guessing it. Why not just do the destruction

Comment: I think I now need a definition for "any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor", does my example depend on the side effects of `~vector`? I wouldn't say so, and in that case there would be no UB.

Comment: Being able to "release" the memory used by a `vector` is quite useful for transferring ownership.

Comment: Just do the destructor then it doesn't matter

Comment: Allowing the destructor to run would call the destructor for each element of the vector, which is not the desired behaviour when you just want to release ownership of that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not undefined behavior. The destructor of an object does not need to be called. [(C++ standard example)](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6.example-1)

N.B: Nevertheless, the life-time of the int object created by the placement new expression ends at the closing brace in you example. An object life-time ends if the destructor for that object is called or if its storage is released or reused [[basic.life]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1):

```
{
  std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(int), alignof(int)> storage;
  int& i = *new(&storage) int;
} // storage released => end of life of the int.

{
  std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(std::pmr::vector<int>),
                                alignof(std::pmr::vector<int>)> vec_storage;
  auto& vec = *new(&vec_storage) std::pmr::vector<int>(&mbr);
  vec.resize(N);
} // end of life of the vector, without destructor call

{
  std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(std::pmr::vector<int>),
                                alignof(std::pmr::vector<int>)> vec_storage;
  auto& vec = *new(&vec_storage) std::pmr::vector<int>(&mbr);
  vec.resize(N);
  // next statement end the life of the vector refered by vec, no destructor called
  auto& vec2 = *new(&vec_storage) std::pmr::vector<int>(&mbr);
} // end of life of the vector referred by vec2, no destructor called
```

N.B.2: in the last block, as no destructor is called, you will have a memory leak. But memory leaks are allowed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if you add a citation to your first sentence I would be happy to accept this.

Comment: @nitronoid I can't find a quote for that. But I found an exemple inside the C++ standard. I hope it will be satisfying enough.